# Firebase: Persistencia - ¿Prioridad en la actualización en offline?

Tags: android, firebase

Tengo habilitada la persistencia en mi aplicación, para mantener actualizada la BD después de tener el dispositivo en offline:

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`

He realizado la siguiente prueba:
1º.- He deshabilitado los datos y la wifi del dispositivo.

2º.- He modificado un registro de la BD, desde la consola Firebase.

3º.- He modificado el mismo registro, pero en le dispositivo, con otro dato distinto al que modifiqué en la BD.

4º.- He activado la wifi y al entrar en la aplicación se ha actualizado la información del dispositivo con los datos de la BD de Firebase.

Hasta aquí todo es correcto ya que ha funcionado la persistencia.

Pero luego he realizado la misma prueba PERO primero actualicé la información del dispositivo y luego la de la BD.  Supuse que ahora la información de la BD se actualizaría con la del dispositivo, pero no ha sido así, se ha actualizado el dispositivo con la modificación del la BD.  Yo suponía que Firebase tendría alguna marca de tiempo, o algo similar, para determinar qué dato es más reciente y saber qué dato es actualizable y cual no.

Entonces, ¿Qué criterio sigue Firebase para saber qué dato es más reciente?

Comment: Probablemente solo modificaste los datos localmente y no se los enviaste a firebase, podrias subir el codigo de como lo hiciste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que existe una condicion de carrera entre el dato que viene desde Firebase y el dato que queres poner

Si bien es cierto que Firebase guarda un timestamp y cuando vuelve a venir tu conexion trata de reenviar tu dato a la base de datos, tambien es cierto que tambien mantiene un socket escuchando por datos en cierta referencia.

Si la referencia en la que se escucha es la misma a la que se le quiere poner el dato de manera offline puede que exista una carrera en la cual se ponga el valor de tu bd antes de escribir.

Para solucionar este problema hay dos soluciones

una es usar `.addListenerForSingleValueEvent`  en tu referencia, lo que va a hacer es dispararse solo una vez para obtener los datos, por lo que cuando vuelva tu conexion, si los datos ya han sido cargados una vez, se desprende el socket de escucha y vas a poder actualizar tu valor sin problema.

Otra es usando updateChildren para actualizar el nodo en vez de setear su valor

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data

por ultimo , seria una buena practica que uses transacciones ya que son atomicas y aseguran tus procesos asyncronos

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Transaction

Recorda que cuando se va la conexion y regresa, debes estar en el mismo contexto en la app en la que dejaste pendiente esa escritura, por que si te moves de pantallas mientras hiciste una peticion, el mismo lifecycle de la actividad va a matar a los trabajos pendientes que quedaron, o va a ser recogido por el GC (garbage collector)